# YII migrations and by default values for table columns

Tags: php, database, yii, migration, database-migration

```
public function up(){

        $this->createTable('POST', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'isremoved' => 'integer NOT NULL',
            'removaldate' => 'timestamp NULL',
            'post' => 'text NOT NULL',
            'creationdate' => 'timestamp NOT NULL',
        ));
}
```

This is the up function for migration. As u see it is query for creating new table. By default YII creates default value for timestamp column equal to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and crates additional parameter and sets it equal to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I do not need current value for timestamp and i do not need to update this column on updating row. What i must to do? By the way, u use MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage off the MySQL Create Table Script:

```
show create table tablename
```

Which gives:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
....
....
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
...
```

Now Add that to the migration:

```
'timestamp' => 'timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

Answer (score 6):

For google users like me: Yii2 now has it [out of the box](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-columnschemabuilder.html#defaultExpression()-detail).

Now you can add `->defaultExpression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` to your definition.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set other default value, null for example

```
public function up(){

        $this->createTable('POST', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'isremoved' => 'integer NOT NULL',
            'removaldate' => 'timestamp DEFAULT NULL',
            'post' => 'text NOT NULL',
            'creationdate' => 'timestamp DEFAULT NULL',
        ));
}
```

Comment: It is not null column. But the problem is if default value is set as current_timestamp(it is not a problem 'cause anyways i'll set a needed value) then ON UPDATE value is set too. I don't want the value to be modified on updatind row

Comment: I don't understand what's your case than, sorry